# Nested filtering with jq

Tags: json, shell, select, command-line, jq

First time user of jq and I'm wanting to filter out objects based on a value within them and I'm struggling to figure it out.

I have a big json file with lots of product data like what's below. I'm wanting to filter out based upon which website_ids they have.

Example Input:

```
[{
    "product_id": "2",
    "sku": "PROD2",
    "name": "Product Name 2",
    "set": "4",
    "type": "simple",
    "category_ids": {
      "item": "15"
    },
    "website_ids": {
      "item": [
      "1",
      "4"
    ]}
},{
    "product_id": "3",
    "sku": "PROD3",
    "name": "Product Name 3",
    "set": "4",
    "type": "simple",
    "category_ids": {
      "item": "15"
    },
    "website_ids": {
      "item": [
      "1",
      "2"
    ]}
}]
```

Desired output:

```
[{
    "product_id": "2",
    "sku": "PROD2",
    "name": "Product Name 2",
    "set": "4",
    "type": "simple",
    "category_ids": {
      "item": "15"
    },
    "website_ids": {
      "item": [
      "1",
      "4"
    ]}
}]
```

I've tried a few different things but I'm clearly just not getting it.

`jq 'map(.website_ids.item[] | contains("4"))'`

Gives me:

```
[
  false,
  true,
  false,
  false
]
```

Which seems to match the website_ids items I want, but I'm not sure how to get the full JSON object from that.

Any help would be super appreciated! Thanks.

EDIT:

I've used this and it works with my example:

`map(select(.website_ids.item[] | contains("4")))`

What I've realised is that my example and the file I was actually testing on have some differences.

Sometimes a product has this for the website_id items:

"website_ids": {
      "item": "2"
   }

Which results in the error:

`Cannot iterate over string ("2")`

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is add a `select` call in your map function, like so:

```
jq 'map(select(.website_ids.item[] | contains("4")))'
```

After your edit, it's a bit more complicated, but it can be worked around by checking the type of `.website_ids.item` and then based off of that type, doing a contains check or a simple equality check:

```
map((select((.website_ids.item | type) == "array") | select(.website_ids.item[] | contains("4"))), (select((.website_ids.item | type) == "string") | select (.website_ids.item == "4")))
```

Here it is formatted a bit more readable:

```
map(
    (select((.website_ids.item | type) == "array") | select(.website_ids.item[] | contains("4"))),
    (select((.website_ids.item | type) == "string") | select (.website_ids.item == "4"))
)
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually figured that out shortly after posting. However, I now realise why that wasn't working for me with my actual data before. If you see the edit on my post you'll see what I mean.

Comment: @Wisey, editing a question after being given an answer correct for the originally-asked content is not welcome here; the right thing to do is to accept that correct answer, and then ask a new and separate question focused narrowly on the remaining issue, excluding any content already covered in the previous, already-answered question. Questions that change after being correctly answered are called "chameleon questions", if you see the term thrown around on [meta]. If Marcus *hadn't* already edited the answer to cover the new version of the question, I'd be rolling the change back.

Comment: @Marcus - Thank you that's perfect! I understand the map function better now that I see it like that.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - Sorry, I didn't mean to, I didn't see the reply until I had already edited my original question. I will keep that in mind in future though!